# How do I update SlicerCaches using win32com?

Tags: excel, slicers

I have an Excel document with a Slicer, depending on what you choose it will update charts, which I can copy to clipboard and save.  However I need to update the Slicer with the appropriate options.  This is what I have figured out so far:

```
`      
import win32com.client as win32

# Initilize Excel
excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')

# Open Excel Workbook
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(f"C:\\Users\\me\\Downloads\\RMA_Models.xlsx")

# Target Correct Worksheet
ws=wb.Sheets("Key Vendor Pivot Table & Charts")

# Target SlicerCache
sl = wb.SlicerCaches("Slicer_MFG__Clean")
sl.ClearAllFilters()
sl.SlicerItems[10]
`
```

SlicerItems[10] is the one I want to click on to get the chart I need.  But I can't figure out how to do that.  Any help would be appreciated.

Normally or when clearing filters it creates a graph of all manufactures. Selecting a single one with update the graphs to reflect just that manufacture.  I need to break it down to show top 3 manufactures.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

```
for partner in ('VendorA','VendorB','VendorC'):
    sl.ClearAllFilters()
    for item in sl.SlicerItems:
        if item.Name == partner:
            item.Selected = True
        else:
            item.Selected = False
```